# calculate button to update values

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a script that will take a dollar amount value in a cell and run it through a small calculation and spit out the percent value in the **SAME** cell.

Example image:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjS2H.jpg)

The goal would be to have a macro that will take the value of **B2** ($10) and replace it with the value **10%** (**B1** divided by the input value of **B2**) Can this be done?

Comment: And why not have that percentage in another column, so that you retain the value and the percentage?

Comment: that example looks like you just want to have e2 be calculated to be the percentage b2/b1.  So, in e2 you would just have `=b2/b1` and format it to a percentage.  Or else you are wanting to have b2 be calculated as the amount of b1*e2%, and assuming b2 is formatted as a percentage, you would just have , in b2, `=b1*e2`

Comment: Sorry I cannot view my own image at work. I believe I had the wrong image up originally. The goal is to not have the original value retained. I have a large portion of cells that will need this accomplished so I am making it as basic as I can for the community to add the rest later myself. I need the value in B2 to be replaced with the value of B1/B2.

Comment: So `Range("B2").Value = Range("B2").Value/Range("B1").Value`?

Comment: That looks right, I am pretty rough on my VBA. Is there a code to also change the formatting of that cell to be a percentage?

Comment: `Range("B2").NumberFormat = "0.00%"`